# Create a lambda function within a method

Tags: java, sql, lambda

I am trying to write some imitation of SQL: that is, I get a structured query (e.g. "SELECT name FROM * WHERE ..." - not exactly my query, but that's the idea), and I would like to get a lambda function to apply to a database. The lambda function would be something like chained filter statements.

I have the parsing complete, but moving from that to returning a lambda is tricky. I have been looking [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) but I am confused about the mechanics of this, and how it would be implemented.

Some guidance would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider using some existing and tested implementation like Hibernate or jOOQ

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be done by conceptually processing each element, one at a time.  For this, Java already has the `Stream` data type, which comes with the `Stream.filter(...)` method that takes a `Predicate` which is a functional interface that determines a `boolean` true / false value for an item in the `Stream`.

```
List<Milk> expired = milkInventory.stream().filter(
   u -> u.age > 14
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that the `Predicate` in this example is the lambda `u -> u.age > 14`

You can apply multiple filters on the same stream.

```
`stream.filter(...).filter(...).collect(...)`
```

And if you find you need to construct your `Predicate`s as classes you can  even do

```
public class AgeFilter extends Predicate<Integer> {
  ... implementation here ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple usage of lamda function compose, andThen. Let's first define two simple functions - times2 and squared.

```
 Function<Integer, Integer> times2 = e -> e * 2;

 Function<Integer, Integer> squared = e -> e * e;
```

Next, let's combine them, using compose and andThen.

```
 times2.compose(squared).apply(4);  
 // Returns 32

 times2.andThen(squared).apply(4);  
 // Returns 64
```

As you can see, the difference between compose and andThen is the order they execute the functions. While the compose function executes the caller last and the parameter first, the andThen executes the caller first and the parameter last.